# Округления верхних краёв подчеркивания

Tags: html, css

Я сделал свой класс для подчёркивания текста. Хочу у него округлить края, но округляются только нижние. Поможете?

```
.red-underscore
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, red 0%, red 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 15px;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нормально всё округляется. Просто он занимает высоту больше, чем весь элемент, поэтому края не видно. если сделать не `background-size: 100% 15px;`,  а `background-size: 100% 22px;` - станет понятно. Но без разметки html и бОльшего кода css советовать что-то сложно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только нижние округляются потому, что это края всего элемента с текстом, а не градиента. Грубо говоря, градиент не сам имеет скругленные края, а выглядывает из-под "трафарета" в форме блока с текстом. Попробуйте псевдоэлементы:

```css
.red-underscore {
    width:100px;
    color:#eee;
    font-size:40px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:0.5em;
    padding-right:1em;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    padding-left:10px;
}


.red-underscore:before {
    content:'';
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, blue 0%, red 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    right:1em;
    bottom:7px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:-1;
}


.red-underscore:after {
    content:'';
    background-color:#000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-underscore">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сильно помог!